# Twilio and Ngrok with password?

Tags: python, flask, twilio, password-protection, ngrok

I'm using Flask, Twilio, and Ngrok to run a program on a Raspberry Pi. The username/password authentication in ngrok is working fine when I access the ngrok URL on a browser, but I want to be able to pass the username/pw in a text message to authenticate and then carry on with the code.

Is it even possible?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def camera_toggle():
    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    from_message = request.values.get('Body', None)

    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message("Please enter your username:password")
    if ":" not in from_message:
        #Split the username/password, then somehow login??
        return str(resp)
    else:
        from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
        from_message = request.values.get('Body', None)
        if callers[from_number] == "John Doe":
            if from_message == "CameraON":
                subprocess.call(["bash", "camera.sh"])
        return str("Please enter the keyword to turn on the camera")
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are using HTTP basic auth with ngrok, then you can set your Twilio webhook URL to use the username and password in the URL for incoming SMS messages.

For example, if your username and password was "username" and "password" and your ngrok URL was `secure.ngrok.io` then you can set the incoming webhook URL for messages in your Twilio console to:

`https://username:password@secure.ngrok.io/sms`

Check out more on [securing your webhook endpoints in the Twilio documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#http-authentication).

Comment: Thank you, @philnash.  I am having trouble understanding the example code and I am not sure how to implement what I need.  I don't see how I would include logic to prompt the user for the username/password via SMS.

Comment: Oh, if you wanted to prompt the user for a username and password then you can't do it with ngrok's HTTP basic authentication. You'd have to build the authentication into your application itself.